# Laravel 5.2 : Mail not sending from cron-job, getting error from mail response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

Working on Laravel 5.2, able to send a mail from API call, but getting an error while sending from the cron/scheduled job,

**File permissions** :

- app/storage/framework - 777
- vendor/laravel/framework/src - 777

**Error message is** :

```
local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: errors' in /var/www/html/v1/storage/framework/views/258d88011f525ffcc409e29eafacedd9b8048ff6.php:24
```

The complete error message from log file :

```
[2018-09-11 10:16:01] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: errors' in /var/www/html/v1/storage/framework/views/258d88011f525ffcc409e29eafacedd9b8048ff6.php:24
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/v1/storage/framework/views/258d88011f525ffcc409e29eafacedd9b8048ff6.php(24): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/html/v...', 24, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(42): include('/var/www/html/v...')
#2 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(149): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(120): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#5 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(85): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#6 /var/www/html/v1/storage/framework/views/80be09fc2f6488124101d105b7ffca95eab87ca3.php(333): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#7 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(42): include('/var/www/html/v...')
#8 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(149): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#10 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(120): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#11 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(85): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#12 /var/www/html/v1/storage/framework/views/60a5d080fd9cde632d9140e6526f07954901cab0.php(17): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#13 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(42): include('/var/www/html/v...')
#14 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#15 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(149): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/html/v...', Array)
#16 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(120): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#17 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(85): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#18 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(441): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#19 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(321): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->getView('welcome', Array)
#20 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php(161): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->addContent(Object(Illuminate\Mail\Message), 'welcome', NULL, NULL, Array)
#21 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(221): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send('welcome', Array, Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/html/v1/app/Http/Controllers/ExpenseController.php(1733): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('send', Array)
#23 /var/www/html/v1/app/Http/Controllers/ExpenseController.php(1733): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send('welcome', Array, Object(Closure))
#24 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\ExpenseController->sendMailFromCronTemplate()
#25 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#26 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(602): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array, Array)
#27 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(502): Illuminate\Container\Container->callClass('\\App\\Http\\Contr...', Array, NULL)
#28 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/CallbackEvent.php(61): Illuminate\Container\Container->call('\\App\\Http\\Contr...', Array)
#29 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php(61): Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\CallbackEvent->run(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#30 [internal function]: Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand->fire()
#31 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#32 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#33 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#35 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(794): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(186): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#37 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#38 /var/www/html/v1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#39 /var/www/html/v1/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#40 {main}
```

Cron function from app/console/kernal.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call('\App\Http\Controllers\ExController@sendMailFromCron')->cron('* * * * *');
    }
```

Mail function :

```
 $data = array('name' => "Sample");
 $to = 'myname@company.com';

 $result = Mail::send('welcome', $data, function($message) use ($to) {
           $message->from('myname@company.com', 'Sample');
           $message->to($to);
           $message->subject('E-Mail Example');
 });
```

Comment: show us your cron function

Comment: give 777 to whole storage/ as well as bootstrap/

Comment: Are you using ```error``` variable in blade template of your e-mail?

Comment: @Exterminator - means app/console/kernal?

Comment: @AfrazAhmad - getting error while try to change  `$ chmod -R 777 storage
chmod: changing permissions of ‘storage/framework/cache/94’: Operation not permitted
`

Comment: add sudo before this command

Comment: @Dev - I am not using any blade template to mail, but its connecting to `resource/view/inc/message.blade.php`

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777    storage/

Comment: @AfrazAhmad - Yupp, will check mail function now.

Comment: Try to clear your server cache also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179809/discussion-between-151291-and-afraz-ahmad).

Comment: @151291 cron function in which mail is called

Comment: @Exterminator - updated my question with few more details, its Mail::send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Laravel 5.2 doc's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail), the first argument of `Mail::send()` is the template and in your snippet you've specified the `welcome` template.

The `welcome` template is usually used as the default view for the web front end, not for mail. I think what you want to pass is `emails.welcome` as per the doc's, but that won't exist by default. Just create an emails directory in `resources/views/emails` and create a welcome.blade.php inside there with what you want emailed.